# Is it safe to return a structure of strings?

Tags: c++

I am writing a function parser which needs to recursively split data, i.e.

`aba$(2)cd$(5)efg`

returns `aba`, `$(2)`, and `$(5)efg`

I need to make a structure that can hold three strings,

```
struct split3 {
   std::string before, middle, after;
};
```

If I assign the strings in the structure then return them, is this safe? If its not, what should I do? I don't really think its safe, because there is no copy constructor for the structure, and the strings would exist on the stack, which wouldn't exist (for long, anyway) after returning?

i.e.

```
split3 func(...) {
s = split3();
... do stuff to s.before, s.middle, s.after;
return s;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is safe. Otherwise nobody would use `std::string`.

Comment: It's perfectly safe. `std::string` is responsible for allocating and deleting any memory required.

Comment: As for the edit, the compiler-generated copy constructor will copy each element of the struct individually so that works too.

Comment: @Ed S.  I must have made a mistake typing it here.

Comment: What does "safe" mean?

Comment: The compiler will provide you with a copy constructor for split3. What does the compiler generated copy constructor do you ask? Why it calls the copy constructor of any member objects of the class. std::string provides a copy constructor that does the right thing, so the copy constructor of split3 does the right thing as well. (remember classes and structs are the same in C++, except a structs access defaults to public)

Comment: Rule of thumb: `std::string` is as safe as `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. split3 will be given a default copy constructor, which will just call the copy constructor for string 3 times. Which sounds like it's what you want.

It's true that the original strings you created on the stack inside func() will no longer be valid after it returns, but the *copies* inside the split3 object that is returned will be ok.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe (in the correctness meaning). There is no need for explicit copy constructor as default copy constructor will suffice. Your structure will be copied by correctly copying all the 3 strings.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe like others have said. Just remember that it is making a copy. That means if you have a really large structure it is going to have to make a copy of the whole thing. If it's something small like this it doesn't really matter.

Comment: That's not strictly true. An optimizing compiler can optimize return statements to use a move, which is usually quite inexpensive, or even remove the copy/move step altogether in some cases (NRVO).

Comment: An optimizing compiler is going to change the code so it's more efficient right? Does the programmer need to rely on an optimizing compiler to rewrite their code?

Comment: An optimizing compiler's goal is to modify your code so that it gets the same results as what you asked for, but in a faster way. For instance, if your code says `n * 2`, and the CPU is faster at addition than multiplication, it could transform that code to `n + n` in order to get the same result but in a faster way. There are thousands of techniques that optimizers use to do this.

Comment: In the case I mentioned in my first comment, an optimizing compiler can look at the steps of "copy variable A into the return value" followed by "variable A has gone out of scope, destroy it," perform an analysis, and realize that these two steps can be optimized into "move variable A into the return value." Or, with NRVO, the optimizer can observe that "this function always returns variable A, so instead of allocating a separate stack variable for A, put variable A directly into the memory set aside for the return value."

Comment: Interesting, Thanks for your comment.